# Support of the direct image sheaf equals the image?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

$\def\sO{\mathcal{O}}
\def\supp{\operatorname{Supp}}
\def\sI{\mathcal{I}}
\def\sC{\mathcal{C}}
\def\colim{\operatorname{colim}}$I am studying complex spaces using Grauert, Remmert, *Coherent Analytic Sheaves*. In Chapter 2, §5.3 (p. 60), there is this result (where $(X,\sO_X)$ and $(Y,\sO_Y)$ are complex spaces):
[image]

In the proof, I don't understand why equality
$$
\supp f_*(\sO_X)=f(X)
$$
is true. I know how to see $(\supset)$. Namely, one uses the result that for a ring-valued diagram $F:\sI\to\mathsf{Ring}$, one has $\colim F=0$ if and only if $Fi=0$ for some $i\in\sI$. But how one does see $(\subset)$? If $y\in\supp f_*(\sO_X)$, then $f_*(\sO_X)_y\neq 0$, and by the categorical lemma, it follows that $\sO_X(f^{-1}(V))\neq 0$ for all open neighborhoods $V\subset Y$ of $y$, i.e., $f^{-1}(V)\neq\varnothing$ for these neighborhoods. After this, I don't know how to proceed.

---

EDIT: In Chapter 1, §1.4 there is this statement:

[image]

Actually, the argument above works to prove the identity $\supp f_*(\sO_X)=\overline{f(X)}$, so it suffices to show that $f(X)$ is closed. But why should $f(X)$ be closed at all? I guess it has to do somehow with the $\sO_Y$-coherence of $f_*(\sO_X)$.

Comment: Re: the new tag "complex-spaces" and tagging old questions: Please consider using [this meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35451/tag-management-2023) or [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/tagging) to discuss the intended scope of the tag and maybe write up a tag wiki to explain its usage. It's not a good idea to tag a large number of old posts before sorting out the proper usage of the tag itself, especially when the terminology you chose [is ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_space).

Comment: @ElliotYu Thank you for the info. I've just retagged my question to a more precise tag, and I've proposed [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35507/394668) to delete the old tag.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have $y \in Y \setminus f(X)$. Then by Hausdorffness and the open mapping theorem we find an open neighbourhood $x \in U \subseteq Y$ s.t. $U \cap f(X)= \emptyset$. Now we have $f_*(\mathcal{O}_X)(U)=\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(U))=\mathcal{O}_X(\emptyset) = 0$.

As $x \in U$ we can conclude $f_*(\mathcal{O}_X)_x = 0$ and $x$ is not in the support of $f_*(\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Comment: What is the "open mapping theorem"? In the book by Grauert, Remmert they don't address a theorem with that name until p. 107. But the result I quoted is on p. 60.

Comment: It states that an holomorphic map is open. As it is a standard fact from (affine) complex analysis and you only need the affine result here, I think it can be assumed when studying complex geometry.

Comment: Don't you need any additional hypothesis on the dimension of the involved spaces? Consider for example the inclusion $\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^m$, for $n<m$? In the statement from Grauert, Remmert, $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary complex spaces. Does the $\mathcal{O}_Y$-coherence of $f_*(\mathcal{O}_X)$ imply somehow the additional necessary hypotheses for the open mapping theorem to work?

Comment: Note that the open mapping theorem only applies to holomorphic functions, i.e. maps $X \to \mathbb C$. For a higher-dimensional counterexample, consider $\mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C^2, (x,y) \mapsto (x, xy)$. It's image is neither closed nor open.